# Error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to run this code for a submit button on a form that is supposed to insert the values into the Excel sheet and each time it is clicked will move down a row and insert values again. Getting the "438" error though.

```
Sub AddPromotionButton_Click()

   Dim LR As Long

 

   LR = Worksheets("New Promotion").cell(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

   Range("A" & LR).Value = NameofPromotion.Value

   Range("B" & LR).Value = InvoiceText.Value

   Range("C" & LR).Value = ChildOffer.Value

   Range("D" & LR).Value = FlatorPercentage.Value

   Range("E" & LR).Value = DiscountRate.Value

   Range("F" & LR).Value = OperatingCenter.Value

   Range("G" & LR).Value = FTA.Value

   Range("H" & LR).Value = MarketArea.Value

   Range("I" & LR).Value = DurationofPromo.Value

   Range("J" & LR).Value = StartDate.Value

   Range("K" & LR).Value = EndDate.Value

   Range("L" & LR).Value = GL.Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this ...

```
LR = Worksheets("New Promotion").cell(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

... to this ...

```
LR = Worksheets("New Promotion").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```